# How to put a walking Man animation into SceneKit Xcode from Blender 3D program SWIFT

Tags: ios, animation, blender, scenekit

If I Have a Man that I created in blender as a Mesh. Then I import that Man into Xcode as a "`.dae`" file object. Now lets say I want that man to go from 
point **A------------------to----------------------point B** here. To do this I just assign an action to the Man to go from Point to Point B but now the Man will just look like he's basically stuff as a rock. and his feet and arms won't be moving at all even though his over all body is moving to Point B. So How do I get him to do the walking animation and look like his feet are moving and walking. lets say that a created this animation in Blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked through this the other day...

1. Create keyframe animation within Blender
2. Export to Collada (.dae)
3. Load into a SceneKit scene (`let scene = SCNScene(named:"myCollada")`)
4. Set the `SCNView` scene

Camera, lights, animations will be as it was within Blender. And the animation autoplays...at least in my experience.

Comment: It works if there is no skeletal animation in .dae. If animation created with skeleton and joints it won't be animated in SCNScene

Comment: By skeletal do you mean model motion animations? I've got a rotating, translating object (using delta-transform/position) and that's not coming through either :/

Answer (score 5):

There is an example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html

You need to load a "walk" animation (authored in Blender or another 3D authoring software). And start it with "addAnimation:forKey:".

Comment: In Apple example (Fox) there is walk.scn file but it's empty if you try to view it in Xcode. There is some settings in blender to save animations that you can't see in Xcode?